# Number of cents needed to return change in C language

Tags: c

I am writing a program using C language where we ask user to enter number of items they want to buy, their unit price and we then calculate total price with and without tax. If total price with tax is equal to $5 or higher we then return them appropriate amounts of dollars back. We have to determine the total number of loonies they need to get and 1 cents. I have figured out everything, but I can't find out how to calculate 1 cents.

This is what I have for loonies:

```
loonies = cash / 1;
```

This will find the total number of loonies I need to give back, but I am getting on pennies.

Comment: What if the price is less than $5? They have to supply exact change?

Comment: Show what you have done and where your **specific** problem is. There are very few clairvoyants on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the amount in terms of cents (ie, $5.03 would be 503) and use the modulus operator.

As an example, to determine the number of cents in $5.03, you would do 503 modulus 100.